# Unarchive UIImage object returns CGSizeZero image using NSKeyedUnarchiver on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, ios8

I have this code working on iOS 7:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.imageView.image];
UIImage *imageCopy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:imageData];
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(imageCopy.size));
```

but on iOS 8, `imageCopy`'s size is always zero. Same thing happens when I archive `UIImageView`, the unarchived imageView's image has a zero size. I found out that in iOS 7, `UIImage` header is like:

```
UIImage : NSObject <NSSecureCoding, NSCoding>
```

but on iOS 8 it is :

```
UIImage : NSObject <NSSecureCoding>
```

It looks like the `NSCoding` protocol is missing on iOS 8. I have to encode the actual image data: `UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image)` instead of the image to make sure I get a good image back.

Does anyone know why this happens? Is it for backward compatibility? I noticed in iOS earlier version `UIImage` doesn't conform to `NSCoding`.

Comment: This code works fine on iOS8/Xcode6 at least for me. I get {0, 0} only for images that are nil, for all others I get {640, 640} etc

Comment: Not working for me, I am using Xcode6 Version 6.0.1 on iOS8, how about you?

Comment: Version 6.0.1 (6A317) and tried on iPhone 5s.

Comment: have the same problem on xcode 6.4. The solution below worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UIImage : NSObject <NSSecureCoding>` is not a problem because `NSSecureCoding` inherits `NSCoding`.

Anyway, I confirmed the problem can be reproduced with following code:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"myImage"];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:img];
UIImage *imgCopy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
NSLog(@"%@, %@", imgCopy, NSStringFromCGSize(imgCopy.size)); // -> (null), {0, 0}
```

On the other hand, the following code works as expected:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"myImage"];
UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage scale:img.scale orientation:img.imageOrientation];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:img2];
UIImage *imgCopy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
NSLog(@"%@, %@", imgCopy, NSStringFromCGSize(imgCopy.size)); // -> <UIImage: 0x7fa013e766f0>, {50, 53}
```

I don't know why, maybe bug?

I think, this is related to `imageAsset` or `traitCollection` property introduced in iOS8

Comment: Really! I get the same result as yours,the other way worked, I firstly found the problem on imageView, after unarchiving, imageView copy's image size is zero,what do you think has caused that? The code in my question used self.imageView.image, the image is from cache, not from the resource bundle.

Comment: Well, I have no idea, sorry :)

Comment: i spend on it half of day. facepalm.
AND ANSWER WORKS!